# Difference between impulse and step response.

Tags: matlab

My question is quite simple but I have some difficulties finding an answer to it. I was wondering what was the difference between the impulse and step response functions in MATLAB. The "help" section did not help me to understand the difference.

Comment: It might help if you list exactly what the functions are that you're using, and what if any toolboxes might be installed.

Comment: I'm looking at the help sections and they are both pretty detailed. Is there something specific that you don't understand? Do you understand the difference between an impulse input and a step input?

Answer (score 0):

The impulse response provides the response of the system (output response) for the exact input value given. For instance, if I need the output response for the time input of 10 secs I get the output accordingly. On the other hand, step response provides the response within the limit of the input.